# this batch of honey

Tags: uncountable-nouns, demonstrative

Let's say we have a number of batches of honey, each batch consisting of a number of containers). Two of the batches belong to John. One of those two batches is expensive and the other one isn't.

Which of the following sentence would be correct in that context:

a. This honey is expensive. That one isn't.

b. This honey belonging to John is expensive. That other one isn't.

c. This honey of John's is expensive. That other one isn't.

d. This honey of John is expensive. That other one isn't.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Contrary to what the other answers say, you *can* in fact use uncountable nouns to refer to specific instances of that uncountable noun rather directly in English. More specifically, pretty much *any* uncountable noun referring to a substance or material can be used in a countable sense to refer to specific instances or varieties of that substance or material.

‘That honey’ could be ‘that bottle of honey’, or ‘that batch of honey’, or ‘that variety of honey’, or ‘that type of honey’. It could even be ‘the honey in that vat’, or ‘the honey in that tank’, or, on a particularly bad day, ‘that giant wave of honey rushing down the street’. It’s ambiguous without further context, *but it is grammatically valid*, and it will generally be understood correctly by most native speakers (provided they have enough of the required context).

*However*, this usage is something that prescriptivists seem to love to hate, just like singular ‘they’ or ending sentences with prepositions. As a result you will often be told it’s wrong. It is, however, used regularly in actual speech (for example use of ‘a beer’ to refer to a can/bottle/mug/tankard of beer), and more importantly, *native speakers have no issue in most cases understanding what it means*.

So ‘this honey’ is perfectly correct grammatically, as is using ‘that one’ as a contrastive.

That leaves us with your usage of posessives. Example D sounds like the honey is made of John, not like it belongs to John. Given your description you’re not talking about a mellified man¹, so it's incorrect. Examples B and C are technically correct, but sound out of place because ‘this’ is often not used together with posessives (I unfortunately cannot explain *why* this would be the case though).

Given this, A would be the most ‘correct’ option here.

---

1: Many people probably have no idea what a ‘mellified man’ is, but I’m intentionally not linking a definition here because it is likely to be nightmare inducing for some people. If you *really* want to know (you probably don’t), then look up that exact term on the English-language Wikipedia.

Comment: Also "He sells two honeys - clover and leatherwood" meaning honey made from two different types of plant. Similarly two sugars - sucrose and glucose.

Comment: I think the objection was more to “that one isn’t.” in other words, in the sentence, “This [batch of] honey is expensive and that one isn’t,” the two clauses should be parallel, but “this batch” parallels “that one [batch],” and “that honey” doesn’t sound as natural.

Comment: However, as you say, “this honey” and “that honey” could mean this *kind of* honey and that *kind of* honey, which makes sense in context.

Comment: @ruakh A typo, I meant singular they. Fixed now.

Comment: I agree that A, B and C are all technically correct, but A and C sound equally natural to me. (The construction in C is admittedly less common, but I think that's just because the situation is more specific.)

Comment: I disagree with the assumption: `Example D sounds like the honey is made of John, not like it belongs to John` No speaker or listener would ever think *the honey of John* is ***honey made from John***, it's just missing the possessive apostrophe.  We also use "of" to denote the possessor of something …*This honey **of John's** is absolutely delicious.*… Meanwhile, "This honey and that honey" would probably be interpreted as "This (single jar of) honey is …and that single jar of)… " unless context tells us that more than one jar is involved.

Comment: I agree with almost everything in this answer, except the example of "a beer". There's a difference between "a beer" in the two following sentences: "I had a beer before leaving the pub"; "I tasted a particularly bitter beer tonight". The latter is a good example of an uncountable noun used in a countable sense, but in the former, "a beer" is a synecdoche and really means "a pint of beer".

Comment: I disagree with using "that one" for honey, as honey cannot be "one". There is a big difference between saying "this/that honey" and explicitly using a number for it.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Context establishes though that it’s not honey in the generic sense, at which point you are talking about jars, or batches, or varieties, or some other specific instances of the substance (based on experiential knowledge, not some inherent property of the word). People elide the modifier _all the time_ in normal speech though, quite often in a very similar context (for example ‘I liked that [bottle of] wine, but not this one.’, ‘They used this [variety of] steel, not that one.').

Answer (score 7):

Honey is a substance and therefore uncountable. If you want to use *that one* you have to refer to *that batch* (or *those jars).*

> This batch (of honey) is expensive. That one isn't.
>
> This batch of John's honey is expensive. That one isn't.

Comment: Correct. Uncountable nouns can't be counted. Not even up to one: "This honey is expensive, that honey isn't"; I'm not even sure about, "This honey is expensive, the other isn't."

Answer (score 6):

*This honey of John* sounds wrong to me ... *this honey of John's* is much more idiomatic.

Aside from this, and the use of *one* for an uncountable noun that the other answer addresses, your phrases all sound fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to "honey" (uncountable), it is marginally odd to use "one" in the second phrase.  Either refer to batches: "This batch is expensive, that one isn't" Or don't use "one":  "This honey is expensive, that isn't."

The context is extremely artificial, and in a realistic context there is probably a better solution:

> The box on the left contains manuka honey, which is more expensive than the regular honey.  The box on the right contains regular honey.

See, all the problems with "one" vanish when the context is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re comparing countable nouns, such as batches or bottles (of honey), you might say,

> This bottle of honey is expensive. That one isn’t.

> This batch is expensive.  That one isn’t.

The two clauses should be parallel, and “one” would not normally parallel an uncountable noun like “honey.” Although I might (informally) ask for “a water” or even “Two waters, please,” at a restaurant, I wouldn’t call glasses of water, ”*this water and that one.” I also don’t (in American English) call portions of honey “*a honey.”  “Her water and mine” does work for me, and so does, “Alice’s honey and Bob’s.”

However, one context when ”that one” does work as a parallel item is when “this honey” means a type of honey. And that makes sense in context.